# Network switch blocks traffic from an embedded Linux device

Tags: linux, networking, router

I have an embedded Linux system running Angstrom v2017.2 and Kernel 4.9.76 with PREEMPT RT.

For some reason I can only connect to the device with a direct wire connection, but the moment I put a switch in between I can not reach it anymore, i.e. ping does not work.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be?

Update: The issue is very likely the bitrate. 1 Gb/s does not seem to work, but 100 Mb/s does.

Comment: So is it a router or a switch? Can you get packet captures (tcpdump/Wireshark) showing which packets go through, or none at all?

Comment: If it's the speed have a look at the switch. Theoretically it should auto negotiate but maybe it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Or the opposite – you're manually setting the speed to something not supported by the other end...

Comment: I am not aware that I set anything manual. When I connect the board to my Desktop PC, dmesg reports 100 Mbits/s, but when I connect it to a router it reports 1Gbit/s. I do not have any tools to set the bitrate, only the baremetal Linux... Probably I will try to cut the wires in the ethernet to make it work... I keep you updated.